# IIS 7 - Windows Authentication not working

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, pipeline, integrated-pipeline-mode

We have several web apps that use Windows Authentication that worked fine on IIS6.  After deploying them to IIS7, Windows Authentication no longer works (we get 401.2 errors) UNLESS we set the web app to use the "Classic Pipeline"

I realize that Forms auth and Windows Auth aren't simultaneously supported as mentioned [here](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2008/02/11/IIS-7.0-Two_2D00_Level-Authentication-with-Forms-Authentication-and-Windows-Authentication.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289317/iis7-and-authentication-problems) - but that is not my issue - I dont have Forms Authentication enabled.  I only have Windows Authentication enabled - but I am always getting the 401.2

Has anyone run into this?  Is there something else I need to do?

Thanks!
-Mike

Comment: Please create a simplest ASP.NET web application and test it on IIS 7.   That can tell you if IIS 7 supports Windows authentication. Don't rush to your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are two immediate thoughts: (1) is Integrated Windows enabled on the server as a feature in the role (2) is the authentication configured in the right part of web.config?  IIS7 stores some of its configuration is web.config, and moving from IIS6 to IIS7 often involves adding extra information.

See also: http://forums.iis.net/t/1153827.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the settings in the web.config move from system.web to system.webserver when changing from classic mode to integrated mode. For example custom httpmodules move into system.webserver. Do you have any httpmodules that are handling custom authentication?