# ASP.NET MVC 4 Mixed authentication mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an MVC application that offers user two options for authentication:
1- Windows Authentication
2- Custom Authentication

Based on user selection:

1- If Windows, the username and password will be dimmed, application will use windows authentication.

2- If custom, user enters username and password to get authenticated.

Does this model work in ASP.NET MVC?

Thanks

Comment: U can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539038/iis7-mixed-mode-authentication

Answer (score 1):

All the solutions I've heard of involve either two applications or two different pages for authentication types.  There is some discussion here about it: 
[ASP.NET MVC and mixed mode authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432845/asp-net-mvc-and-mixed-mode-authentication)