# ASP.NET MVC4 and mixed mode authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have refer following link to implement mixed mode authentication in my application.

[ASP.NET MVC and mixed mode authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432845/asp-net-mvc-and-mixed-mode-authentication)

But the following variable is always empty when I host it in the iis server . Does anybody having idea about it.

Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]