# Login using SQL and LDAP validations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My company has a web portal utilized mostly by internal users and some users access this portal remotely on personal PCs. We also have external clients that use this portal as well. I am upgrading this application into MVC and I am taking advantage of the template provided to log users in and to validate against a SQL table. I have the external users covered. How can I also implement validating against LDAP for internal users?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC and mixed mode authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432845/asp-net-mvc-and-mixed-mode-authentication)

Comment: Yes, Thank you @willman